# How to communicate with a car via Android smartphone?

Tags: java, android

I want to start an app to be used by an Android smartphone to send information to a car. One example would be to unlock the car, but that is not precisly what I want to do is just an example. My question is, how can I communicate with the car? I am thinking of using a webservice, don't know if this would be adecuate for the prototype.

I would appreciate some links, or info to point me in the right direction to enable a communication of some sort with the car, that is adding a modem to the car or something, I don't know much about how to be able to communicate.

Is there a way to communicate in a longer distance, that is not using bluetooth, since bluetooth is for short distances?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html then come back and edit. This site can be cruel if you don't post what the people want to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well @bb2 if you would have seen Google's IO 2011 then you would have found your answer, but dont worry coz I have seen it.

You are looking for something like a development kit that you can use to communicate other devices with your Android phone and the name of that thing is ***ADK***

Here is the link to documentation of that kit

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/adk.html

and a link to google io 2011

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OxzucwjFEEs

Answer (score 0):

Does your car have a system that connects to your phone through bluetooth? If so, I'd look at the bluetooth sdk docs:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html

If you're thinking of making a device to connect to the car, the new Android Device Kit might be what you're looking for:
http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-19736_7-20061529-251.html?tag=mncol;txt